# How do I sort a Nokogiri NodeSet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I am parsing XML returned from the Google contacts API, using XPath in Nokogiri.

```
def getcontact
  doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(open(url))
  doc.xpath('//xmlns:feed/xmlns:entry[xmlns:title[node()]]')
end
```

My controller is:

```
def index
  @mycontacts = getcontact.to_a.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
end
```

My view is:

```
<% @mycontacts.each do |c| %>
  <p> Name: <%= c.xpath('xmlns:title').text %>  Email: <%= c.xpath('gd:email/@address').text %></p>
<% end %>

<%= will_paginate @mycontacts %>
```

I would like to sort by title in alphabetical order and I am wondering how to go about this. I have read that I can use `sort_by`, but how do I select the title from the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work

```
@mycontacts.sort!{|a, b| a.xpath('xmlns:title').text <=> b.xpath('xmlns:title').text}
```

The block tells it to do the comparison based on the .xpath('xmlns:title').text for each object.

Comment: excellent thanks, would you mind explaining how this is working please so i can use again maybe in a different scenario

Comment: what is the <=> doing? is that the comparison?

Comment: Your passing a block, where a,b are any two objects in the array, and <=> is the manner is which you wish for any two objects in an array to be compared, so yes it is the comparison. So for instances lets say I had gotten an array of objects and I wished to sort them by their 'revenue' minus their 'cost', I would do @objects.sort!{|a,b| (a.revenue - a.cost) <=> (b.revenue - b.cost)} which would return an array sorted by profit.

Comment: Using `sort`, instead of `sort_by`, is wasting CPU time. `sort_by` uses a "[Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)", which is very useful when you have to look inside data, or compute something just to do the sort. Both are true with this question. Instead, use `sort_by{ |a| a.xpath('xmlns:title').text }`.